# Embedded attributes in JAXB class

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to map some legacy XML I can't change.  There are several elements that have hundreds attributes exactly the same as some other elements.  The attributes all have the same name postfixed with a number.  So XML might look like this:

```
<someElement custom1="..." custom2="..." custom78=".."/>
<anotherElmenent custom1="..." custom45="..."/>
```

A solution that "works" is to create a base class like so:

```
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class LotsaCustomIds
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String custom1;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String custom2;
 ...
}

@XmlType
public class SomeElement extends LotsaCustomIds
{
        ....
}
```

But it's a shame to use inheritence here, especially since Java only has single inheritence.  What I'd like to do is something like the way JPA/Hibernate do embedded objects, like:

```
@XmlType
public class SomeElement
{
    @EmbeddedAttributes
    private LotsaCustomIds customIds;
        ....
}
```

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to map this use case.  When you use it as `@XmlPath(".")` then it will pull the contents of the child object (`LotsaCustomIds`) into the parent object (`SomeElement`).

```
@XmlType
public class SomeElement
{
    @XmlPath(".")
    private LotsaCustomIds customIds;
        ....
}
```

**Related Information from my Blog**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: That does the trick!  I'm having some problems with the eclipse JAXB though.  My adapters don't work, and wsdl.exe doesn't seem to like the new WSDL that comes out.  I'll look into that.